# Horizontal Scroll of table on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have code:

```css
 td{
  border: 1px #cccccc solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 div {
  max-width: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
    <div>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap Nowrap</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

It worked on PC. Then on mobile i set meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;  maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta http-equiv="collapsable" content="none">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

My table over size screen.
I want it show scroll width of table, and everything out table view friendly for mobile!

Comment: On mobile phones a scrollbar is not visible, you might even be able to scrolle just by swiping the text.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question! My problem was solved because I set the display: table property on div tag

Answer (score 0):

set the display: table property on div tag